# Identifying genes from a list of genes

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a gene list file. Some thing like this

```
    SWT21
    SSA1
    NRP1
    EFB1
    TFC3
    MDM10
```

I have another file which also contains the names of these genes in my list along with other essential information about them. The second file looks like this:

```
chrI    147593  151166  YAL001C -   TFC3
chrI    143706  147531  YAL002W +   VPS8
chrI    142173  143160  YAL003W +   EFB1
chrI    140759  141407  YAL004W +   YAL004W
chrI    139502  141431  YAL005C -   SSA1
chrI    137697  138345  YAL007C -   ERP2
chrI    136913  137510  YAL008W +   FUN14
chrI    135853  136633  YAL009W +   SPO7
chrI    134183  135665  YAL010C -   MDM10
```

I want to extract those lines in the 2nd file which have gene names as are present in first file.

Comment: I really recommend you do not use the answer you accepted. It will fail for cases where one gene's name is included in another.

Comment: @terdon Thanks. Your solution works fine as of now for me.

Answer (score 10):

All you need is a simple `grep`:

```
grep -Fwf gene_list.txt gene_info.txt
```

The options used are:

- -w : Search for whole words, this ensures that the gene name `ERK1` will not match the gene `ERK12` (`-w` is not a standard option but is fairly common)
- -f : Read the patterns to be searched for from a file. In this case `gene_list.txt`.
- -F : Treat the patterns as strings, not as regular expressions. This ensures that a gene name like `TOR*` (if such a thing existed) would not match `TORRRRRR`.

---

NOTE: This assumes that there are **no spaces** around the gene names in your list. If there are, you will need to remove them first (here with GNU `sed`):

```
sed -i 's/ //g' gene_list.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

From an example on the [awk wiki](http://awk.freeshell.org/ComparingTwoFiles):

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[$0];next} $6 in arr' gene_list info_list
```

Explanation copied from the wiki entry:

- `FNR == NR`: This test is true when the number of records is equal to the number of records in the file. This is only true for the first file, for the second file NR will be equal to the number of lines of file1 + FNR.
- `arr[$0]`: This is a classic technique to create an array element index by the whole line. This will create an array with the first names of file1.
- `next`: this will skip to the next record so no more processing is done on file1.
- `$6 in arr`: This will only happen on the records of file2 because of the next. If $1 is present in arr, ie in file1, the default action will be executed and the line will be printed.

Answer (score 4):

For more robustness you could alter the gene list into regular expressions to match at the end of the line. This should work (and be POSIX compatible):

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*$/[[:space:]]*$/' gene_list | grep -wf - gene_info
```

Or with leading space in the `gene_list` (as per the example in the question):

```
sed 's/$/[[:space:]]*$/; s/[[:space:]]//' gene_list |
  grep -wf - gene_info
```

Of course this won't work if there are characters included in the gene names which are interpreted by regular expressions. Atlhough, if this is the case then you need to add extra replace expressions to `sed` to escape them, eg `s:\[:\[:`.

Comment: @terdon, added the `-w` option to grep, this will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, downvote retracted, upvote added. this is still a bad solution for this particular issue hoewever. Gene names can contain `.` and other meta characters, you really don't want to use regexes. No way you can know this from the question of course, but that's another reason why I recommended the OP not use this. I used to use a similar approach in my pipelines and it took me ages to figure out why I was getting unexpected results.

Comment: @terdon, jasonwryan's solution is probably better if you want to match a in particular column I guess. That said you can always something like `grep '[^[:alnum:][:space:]]' to check for potentially problematic characters.

Comment: Take my word for it. There is basically no guessing what can be in a gene name. I have literally spent hours of my life trying to sort out errors like this before discovering grep's `-F` option. But yes, the `awk` approach can indeed be better, as it often is when there are columns involved. It can also be problematic though when you are working through several gigabytes worth of data, since the array needs to be kept in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the gene list is `list.txt` and the info file is `info.txt`, as well as that the gene names never contain whitespace:

```
for item in $(cat list.txt); do grep "\s$item$" info.txt ; done
```

Output:

```
chrI    139502  141431  YAL005C -   SSA1
chrI    142173  143160  YAL003W +   EFB1
chrI    147593  151166  YAL001C -   TFC3
chrI    134183  135665  YAL010C -   MDM10
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use grep command in linux,by giving command like egrep -wi "complete genelist (1) with inducing pipe among genes" "file name containg all genes(2)".Here genelist(1) is your genelist says its 20 in number and geneliust (2) contains file with whole gene (1000 in number
)

Comment: I believe that I sort-of understand what you’re saying, but I’m not sure.  At best, this answer is incomplete; it doesn’t say *how* to do it.  Further, it appears to be wrong; I can’t get it to work (without changing it). Please test it, fix it, and explain it better. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it better, clearer and more complete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).