# How can I compare 2 files and add lines that aren't on the second file?

Tags: text-processing, diff

I have run into a problem while doing some coding, and I need to compare two files, here is an example input file `inputfile1.txt`:

```
car
php
module
so
js
node
array
```

and another input file: `inputfile2.txt`:

```
car
module
js
array
so
```

The two files are compared, and as you see on `inputfile2.txt`, `node` and `php` does not exist.

Here is the output file `outputfile1.txt` produced by `command inputfile1.txt inputfile2.txt > outputfile1.txt`:

```
car
module
js
array
so
php
node
```

The output file adds missing values that appeared on `inputfile1.txt`, but not `inputfile2.txt`. They are the last two lines.

I have tried a few things with `diff` and `grep` but none shows my desired output.

I am using OSX.

Comment: There are some questions similar to this answered before. You should search the site first. Example here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121222/identifying-genes-from-a-list-of-genes

Comment: `cat inputfile{1,2}.txt | sort | uniq > newfile` will do it if you don't care about sorting.

Comment: @cuonglm Yes, i always try searching, but the titles are almost never similar.

Comment: there is also a comm command which show lines in file 1 only, file 2 only or both file.

Comment: This question is missing a question. I guess you're looking for a way to implement `command`? Do you care about the order of elements in the output?

Answer (score 1):

#### with `grep`:

```
grep -Fxvf file2 file1 >> file2 # append to end of file2
```

#### With `sort`:

```
sort -u file[12] > output
```

Comment: +1 But you may want `grep -vxFf file2` just in case file2 contains any regexp meta-characters, such as `.`, etc., and to ensure that all matches are entire-line matches.  Also, your second `grep` command has a stray `)`.

Comment: @JimL. edited, I think this was answered by me when I was new to the site :  )